# JQuery "is not a function" after ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load Cocoen through AJAX with JQuery. It works, but only some of the time.

I have this function to ajax load a javascript file, when it's needed:

```
jQuery.cachedScript = function( url, options ) 
{
    // Allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
    options = $.extend( options || {}, {
      dataType: "script",
      cache: true,
      url: url
    });
   
    // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
    // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
    return jQuery.ajax( options );
};
```

Then when I detect something with the "cocoen" class, it loads it in as needed like so:

```
if ($('.cocoen').length)
{
    $.when(
        $.cachedScript( "/includes/jscripts/cocoen/js/cocoen.min.js"),
        $.cachedScript( "/includes/jscripts/cocoen/js/cocoen-jquery.min.js"),
        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
            $( deferred.resolve );
        })
    ).done(function(){
        $('.cocoen').cocoen(); // image comparison slider
    }); 
}
```

I don't know what causes it, but sometimes it seems to do the "done" function before it's properly loaded? As in chrome tools it says:
"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cocoen is not a function". That is despite the network tab clearly showing both JS files for cocoen being loaded.

What am I doing wrong here? If I refresh, it then works. Seems random, but there must be something I'm not taking into account here.

Comment: Do you need to support IE11, or can you use `Promise.all()` instead of `jQuery.when()`?

Comment: Nope, don't care about IE at all. Got an example of that?

Comment: You could try `Promise.all([Promise.resolve($.cachedScript(/* cocoen.min.js */)), Promise.resolve($.cachedScript(/* cocoen-jquery.min.js */))].done(() => $('.cocoen').cocoen())`, but I'm not sure it'd work if `jQuery.when()` is failing.

Comment: That doesn't work, tells me it's not a function?

Comment: Don't worry about it then. Someone who knows jQuery more can probably be of more help.